# How to parse groovy xml response

Tags: xml, soap, groovy

I am new to Groovy and all webservice stuff. I am really need help with solving my problem.
So, I have xml soap request
which adding new user and I'am getting a response after sending the request:
[![https://i.stack.imgur.com/pggrI.png][1]][1]
And I really need somehow get a Login from responde. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There are [XmlParser](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlParser.html) and [XmlSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html) classes you can import to parse xml.